# three.js make a cutting plane visible

Tags: three.js

In this demo:

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=clipping#webgl_clipping_advanced

if you enable the "visualize" option, you can see the 3d pyramid "cutting" the inside object.

Here:

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=clipping#webgl_clipping

there is a simple 2d plane cutting the object, but there is no such option to "see" the plane. I just started learning threejs and I am not too familiar with any 3d engine (other than fully understanding the math behind it), so I tried some basic stuff, e.g.:

`localPlane.visible = true`

But of course it didn't work. Any 'simple' way to make the second demo display the cutting plane?

Thank you

Comment: My guess is that it's done in two parts: 1) a clipping object, and 2) a visualization object that happens to match the clipping object.

Comment: @Ouroborus thanks. I tried to create a plane by copying the ground - it worked, but I cannot make it transparent and move it/rotate it the way I want it... As you can see in the example, that plane is created through a Vector3d and another parameter (which I can change, looks to be the distance from 0,0,0)

Comment: You'll need to review the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html) as well as learn about 3D transforms, especially about how they're represented and how they go together.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to add the plane in the position you want:

```
const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1.5, 1.5 );
const planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
const plane = new THREE.Mesh( planeGeometry, planeMaterial );
plane.position.copy(localPlane.normal);
plane.position.multiplyScalar(-localPlane.constant);
plane.quaternion.setFromUnitVectors(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), localPlane.normal);
plane.material.opacity = 0.5;
plane.material.transparent = true;
scene.add( plane );
```

And here's what that looks like...

[image: example with plane added]

However, depending on what you are implementing, you may find it easier to create a Plane Mesh in the position you want, and then derive the clipping plane THREE.Plane from that.

If you want to be able to move the clipping plane around, the reasoning involved in moving a Plane Mesh Object3D is probably more straightforward than reasoning about moving a THREE.Plane.

(update)

Another alternative approach I've come across: you could simply use the built in THREE.PlaneHelper, which can be used to visualize any THREE.Plane.

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/helpers/PlaneHelper

The sample code offered on that page is this:

```
const plane = new THREE.Plane( new THREE.Vector3( 1, 1, 0.2 ), 3 );
const helper = new THREE.PlaneHelper( plane, 1, 0xffff00 );
scene.add( helper );
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, let me check it, understand the methods I don't understand yet, and accept it :)

Comment: Another alternative approach, you could use the built in THREE.PlaneHelper, which can be used to visualize any THREE.Plane. 
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/helpers/PlaneHelper